# Stock Android on Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one

Is there a good place that documents how to compile Android from source and put it on Nexus One? For instance, I would like to checkout the source files of Froyo from the official repository and put it on my Nexus One... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this [XDA forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=704561) will give you a good head start.  Note: this is written for the Sapphire.

[Compiling and flashing a Kernel for the N1.](http://androidboss.com/nexus-one-htc-passion-compile-and-flash-a-kernel/)

[Another guide from XDA forums.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=763877)

[Compiling systems apps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=605755).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will start reading them. One related question is that there's a lot of data and apps installed on my N1 as of now. Is there a way I can take a backup of the entire image so that I can flash it back once I am done experimenting with a new build?

Comment: @Legend If you want a backup of just apps and their data, check out TitaniumBackup (requires root).  If you want a backup image of your phone, you'll need to flash a recovery such as Clockwork and run a Nandroid backup.  Download Rom Manager from the Market, it will let you flash Clockwork and run the backup inside of the app.  Again, you're going to need to root your phone first.  See my post about rooting here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone

Comment: @Legend sure thing!  You might want to experiment with flashing another Rom first before you dig into compiling from source.  Just so you know how to Nandroid your phone, flash a rom, play around with it, and revert back to what you had before.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will do as you suggested. Really excited to learn this stuff now :)